Should I stake newly bench-grafted dwarf apple trees?
I know that dwarf apple trees have weak root systems and it's recommended that you stake them.  Does this apply to brand-new grafts?  I have made several whip-and-tongue grafts from purchased dwarf rootstocks (some Geneva 11 and some Bud.9) and potted the new trees, which are about 1 foot tall right now.  Do they need a stake to hold them straight, or can that wait until they're a couple  years more mature and ready to plant in the orchard?

Commercial dwarf and standard apple trees both have very strong root systems due to grafting onto super hardy root stocks known as M9 and M26. Stake as per Rohit.

Bud9 is a brittle one, Geneva11 less so.

It depends on the tree itself.  However, any young tree (as distinct from a bush) can probably benefit with staking.  As soon as it's tall and spindly, then stake it.

Ok, but not necessarily immediately after bench grafting?
